# Python 2.**: How to capture output of print statement to variable (not file) in order to pass to pandas df.query() function

Tags: python, pandas, printing

**EDIT: SOLUTION!!!**

As it turns out, all I needed to do for this to work was `df.query('{}'.format(eval(queryStr)))` and Python treated `queryStr` as if it were the same as `print(queryStr)`. I don't recommend using `eval` all of the time, but in this case it was the best solution for me that I could figure out so far.

**ORIGINAL PROBLEM:**

I have a string (`queryStr`):

```
>>> queryStr
"'(1522000002801<=TIMESTAMP<=1522000034174 or
1522000048441<=TIMESTAMP<=1522000074589) and (RESOURCE==\\'GTEX\\' or
RESOURCE==\\'MOD_FLYBASE\\') and (ACTIVITY==\\'REQ_RESOURCE\\')'"
```

(Note the backslashes--there are 2)

When I print it `queryStr`, I get:

```
>>> print(queryStr)
'(1522000002801<=TIMESTAMP<=1522000034174 or
1522000048441<=TIMESTAMP<=1522000074589) and (RESOURCE==\'GTEX\' or
RESOURCE==\'MOD_FLYBASE\') and (ACTIVITY==\'REQ_RESOURCE\')'
```

Which 1 backslash-- EXACTLY what I want to pass to `df.query()`.

Because when I run `df.query(queryStr)`

(running `df.query()` with two backslashes), I get an error. But when I run:

`df.query('(1522000002801<=TIMESTAMP<=1522000034174 or 1522000048441<=TIMESTAMP<=1522000074589) and (RESOURCE==\'GTEX\' or RESOURCE==\'MOD_FLYBASE\') and (ACTIVITY==\'REQ_RESOURCE\')')`

(`df.query()` with 1 backslash)

I get exactly what I want:

```
       TIMESTAMP  NODE  ID  REFID  USER      ACTIVITY     RESOURCE
1  1522000016966     1   3      3     6  REQ_RESOURCE  MOD_FLYBASE
4  1522000024848     1   6      6    10  REQ_RESOURCE         GTEX
```

**So, my question is:**

How can I capture the 'output' of `print(queryStr)` and pass it to `df.query()`, exactly as it is printed?

*I know that I can pass the output of `print` to a file, and then bring in those lines, but I feel like that's extremely inefficient.*

Thank you!!

**EDIT:**

Please note that `queryStr` is NOT the `.__repr__()` of the string--because then there would be backslashes in front of the first and last quotes. Hence, using solutions involving `.__repr__()` or `.__str__()` have not worked. I quite literally need to somehow 'grab' the output of `print`.

Thank you again!

Comment: Your string doesn't actually have those double backslashes in it, so the problem you're trying to solve doesn't exist. You're just being confused because the _repr_ of the string—the thing that Python shows you when you evaluate the string at the interactive prompt—adds quotes around it and backslash escapes within it. But those aren't part of the string, they're just added by `repr`.

Comment: When you do `print(s)`, the `print` function just calls `str` on each argument, so if you want to get the exact same string that `print` is printing, you can use `str(s)`. But if `s` is already a string, there's no point in doing this—`str(s)` just returns `s` in that case, so you can just use `s` as-is.

Comment: The actual problem here is that your `queryStr` is _already_ the repr of an actual string. You don't want even _single_ backslashes, and you don't want quotes around it. Somewhere, you did something wrong in creating that string, and _that_ is what you need to fix, not the code that uses that string later.

Comment: Also @abarnert df.query(str()) is not supported.

Comment: What do you mean by that? `df.query(str())` is just querying an empty string. But `df.query(str(something))` is fine. It's not often _useful_, because `something` is usually already a string (as it is in your case), but it's certainly _supported_.

Comment: Meanwhile, your edit is wrong. There are _not_ backslashes in front of the quotes around the repr of a string (unless the string has both single and double quotes in it). See [this example on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SunnyMarriedNamebinding).

Comment: Also, "I quite literally need to somehow 'grab' the output of print" quite literally is just using `str`—which is pointless, because it will give you exactly the same thing you already have.

Answer (score -1):

If you prefix the string with 'r', it will indicate to Python that it's a "raw string" and will pass the string *exactly* as you specify it:

```
df.query(r"your \query")
```

This will pass the string 'y', 'o', 'u', 'r', ' ', '\', 'q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'y' -- with the one backslash exactly as you specfiy it.

From the Python docs:  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a
>   letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat
>   backslashes as literal characters.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, there are two problems:
The first is that I'm using python 2.**, not python 3. 
The second is that
 `>>> df.query(r'{}'.format(queryStr))` 
treats it as `(1522000002801<=TIMESTAMP<=1522000034174 or 1522000048441<=TIMESTAMP<=1522000074589) and (RESOURCE=='GTEX' or RESOURCE=='MOD_FLYBASE') and (ACTIVITY=='REQ_RESOURCE')`  (NO Backslashes) and throws an error.

Thoughts?

Comment: Raw strings are in Python 2:  https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html